# If I paid $7.33 for an item,what was the original price?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the formula for this question. I've tried taking the $\$7.33$ & multiply it by $7\%$ sales tax then subtracting that from the $\$7.33$ but not sure if that's correct.

Comment: $x+.07x=1.07x=7.33$

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Exchange. Why not learn how to write maths in MathJax?  There's a guide here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/  You can start by putting dollar signs at the start and end of numbers and they get formatted better.  A percentage sign needs a backslash before it to display properly, as does a dollar sign. If you click to edit your question you'll be able to see how I reformatted it.

Comment: @JoshuaPugh $x$ is the original price. It's the quantity you are trying to find.

Comment: If you paid the price plus the tax, and the tax was $7\%$ of the original price, then you might say the original was $100\%$ and you paid $100\%+7\%=107\%$

Comment: Let $x$ be the original price.  That's the number you're trying to find.  Then you don't have to keep writing "original price".  It's quicker to just write $x$, as long as you remember what it stands for.  Then you can say $1.07x=\$7.33$.  Divide both sides by $1.07$ and that gives you $x$.

Comment: Thanx so much,took a min but it clicked.

Answer (score 4):

If the price without tax is $x$ and the tax is $p%$, then the final price is 
$$x(1+\frac{p}{100})\,.$$

To get the original price you need to divide by $(1+\frac{p}{100})$, which in this case is $1.07$.